# Size and nature of the Fields of the Dead in the Forgotten Realms

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms

**Am I reading [the official map of Faerun](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/map-faer%C3%BCn) right, is the Fields of the Dead (north of Baldur's Gate, as per SCAG) wider than 300 miles**, from the coast to the Forest of Wyrms / Reaching Woods territories? (Meaning that you could fit, for example, Denmark, EU, or almost the entire state of Washington into it? :-o)

Also, am I reading the descriptions in SCAG and elsewhere right, and is this entire area quite similar to the windswept, grassy rolling hills of Scotland and/or Ireland?

Comment: Regarding size: what makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: @Zachiel I may have missed an errata, perhaps. As far as I can remember, something like that did happen around 3.0, where maps turned out to have been given the wrong scale. So far I never used this area of the Realms, though, so I thought it's better to be safe. Also, some sources seem to talk about this area as an extensive battleground full of burial mounds etc... but that would be a bit oversized, wouldn't it, especially considering the population density of the Realms?

Comment: I assume SCAG is the [Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide), right?.

Comment: @Roflo Yes, you're right about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Yes**

I have consulted the 3rd and 4th edition maps of Faerun, as well as the more detailed 3e map of the Sword Coast. All three confirm that scale (more or less). So, by the canon, that is its size.

The answer to your second question is also yes:

> The Fields of the Dead is a vast, rolling plain of
>   windswept grasses that seems to go on to the horizon
>   in every direction.

However it is not completely uncivilised; it does contain small villages, but probably a lower population density than much of medieval Europe:

> Small , stout farmhouses and
>   even a few walled enclosures that contain several such
>   dwellings can occasionally be found a short distance
>   away from the roads and rivers that run through or near
>   the Fields.

Of course, its your campaign world, so you have every right to change it if you want to.

Comment: Can I assume this also means there's been no errata for the 5e map?

Comment: Not any that I am aware of. All official errata is published on the WotC website: http://dnd.wizards.com/search/site/errata